# start/stop jboss 7.1 server from bash script

Tags: bash, jboss7.x

I am new to bash scripting. I know the basic commands of start/stop jboss server i.e. "service jboss start"/"service jboss stop" respectively, but I don't know how to start/stop it from bash scripting. kindly help me in resolving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the 'bin' directory where jboss is unpacked and simply run it from shell:

```
./standalone # to run in foreground (use Ctrl-C to stop)
or
./standalone 2>&1 > jboss.log &  # to run jboss in background, use ps & kill command to stop
```

Before starting, review and edit all settings in standalone.conf, including the JAVA_HOME

To set up jboss start as a Linux service look  [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-configuration/run-jboss-as-service-howto)